# Modifying digraph to make it strongly connected

Tags: algorithms, graphs

I came across this problem and have not been able to find a solution.

Given directed graph $G$, devise an algorithm to find the minimum number of edges to flip/change/transplant such that the modified graph $G'$ has a path from any vertex to any other vertex. That is, we can remove any edge between any two vertices and add them back to the graph any which way.

Anyone have any idea how to solve?

Clarification for edge modification:
You can edit edges any which way for a cost of one move. Once you remove an edge between any two vertices, you can reattach it to the same two vertices but flipped, or attach it to two different vertices entirely, or just have the edge go from the original source vertex to another vertex, or a different source vertex to the same destination vertex.

Comment: Note there is no reason to *remove* edges.

Comment: Answered on stackoverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14305236/minimal-addition-to-strongly-connected-graph.

Comment: If you just want an algorithm, you can simply try all possibilities.

Comment: Is the goal to minimize number of ops? Are flips less expensive than changes?

Comment: The link doesn't answer the question because the question linked is adding edges. You can have an SCC in this problem that has extra edges. Note you cannot add edges, only change edges. You must remove those edges and move them elsewhere if needed. The goal is to minimize the number of ops and flips are the same as changes.

Comment: So flip/change/transplant are all the same thing: delete 1 edge then add 1 edge?

Comment: I think it could be related to the stackoverflow problem:  first you might try to define "useless" edges; edges that when removed don't alter the SCC metagraph.  For instance an edge in the metagraph might have more than one representative in the original graph.  Or a redundant edge within a SCC.  Then you can calculate the minimal additions as in the stackoverflow question.  If your #useless edges >= minimal # additions, then that's your answer.

Comment: Raom, can you [edit] the question to be more precise about what is allowed by a "flip/change/transplant" operation, and what isn't?

Comment: Raorm should confirm it but I think that starting from a->b edge, flip gives b->a, change to c gives a->c and transplant from c gives c->b. Thus, move an edge to anywhere costs at most 1 change + 1 transplant.

Comment: User111398 basically got it right. Basically you can alter edges in any way and it is the same cost. I'll edit the question. the problem is I do not know how to find these useless edges.

Comment: To answer Vince's comment, any modification of a single edge costs just one move. So moving a->b to b->a is one move, a->b to a->c is one move, and a->b to c->b is one move. a->b to c->d or d->c is also one move.

Comment: Raom, please [edit] the question to state more clearly what operations are allowed.  "edit edges any which way" is vague, and does not match what Vince posted.  For instance, can I change edge a->b to c->d in one operation?  Vince's comment would imply no, but "any which way" would make me think yes.  I suggest you add that information to the question.  Don't just leave it in the comments.  We want questions to stand on their own, so people can understand what is being asked without having to read the comments.  Then, flag as 'no longer needed' those comments once you have edited the question.

Comment: I added clarification to the questions. Yes you can edit a->b to c->d in one move.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On solvable instances (not all instances are solvable; see narek Bojikian's comment on my other answer for a simple necessary and sufficient condition), this is **NP-hard by reduction from Directed Hamiltonian Path**. The basic idea is to add enough isolated vertices to the input digraph to force the only possible solution to be a single cycle, and then see whether it is possible to accomplish this with few enough moves that the unmoved edges must form a DHP in the original digraph.

Given an instance of Directed Hamiltonian Path consisting of a digraph $(V, E)$ with $n=|V|, m=|E|$, add $m-n$ isolated vertices. Observe that a single SCC can be formed by rearranging the $m$ edges into an arbitrary cycle that touches each of the $m$ vertices that now exist. This can be done trivially if we are prepared to move all $m$ edges, but if we limit ourselves to moving at most $m-n+1$ edges, then this is possible only if $m-n+1$ edges are moved from somewhere to form a path that connects some vertex $u$ of the original digraph to some new isolated vertex, visits each new isolated vertex in some order, and finally returns to some other vertex $v$ of the original digraph. (We have $u \ne v$ since $u=v$ would leave just $n-1$ edges available to visit all $n$ vertices of the original digraph, which is not enough.) In this case, the unmoved $n-1$ edges that remain necessarily form a path from $v$ to $u$ through the $n$ vertices of the original digraph, and thus constitute a DHP through it. This shows that a YES answer to the constructed instance implies a YES answer to the original problem.

To see that a YES answer to the original DHP problem implies a YES answer to the constructed instance, pick up the $m-n+1$ edges that are not part of the DHP, and construct a path as described above, forming a single cycle comprising all $m$ vertices using just $m-n+1$ moves.

Answer (score 1):

Under the clarified definition of what moves are possible, the problem is unsolvable for many cases, e.g., the 2-vertex graph a->b. (a is not reachable from b, but the only allowed move is to change the graph to a<-b, and then b is not reachable from a.)

Comment: Well solvablilty condition is easy. If $m \geq n$ we can turn the graph into a simple cycle possibley with additional edges and hence solvable. Else not. The problem is to optimize the number of edits I guess.

Comment: @narekBojikian: That's true, but I think the first part of solving any problem is whether it can always be solved. My other answer shows this is NP-hard.